# Python, function to iterate over a file or another row generator

Tags: python, csv, generator

I've a number of functions that expect either the path of a CSV file, or a source that can be turned into a CSV rows generator, such as the standard input or a list (to perform tests).

I've written this function:

```py
def process_doc_rows ( rows_source ):
    if isinstance ( rows_source, str ):
        # Open the file with the csv reader
        with open ( rows_source ) as csvf:
            yield from process_doc_rows ( csvf )
        return
    
    elif isinstance ( rows_source, io.TextIOBase ):
        # This includes stdin
        rows_source = csv.reader ( rows_source, delimiter = "\t" )

    yield from rows_source
```

which I can invoke this way:

```py
def process_rows ( rows_src ):
  l = 0; res = "";
  for row in process_doc_rows ( rows_src ):
    print ( "L:%d, Name:%s, Surname:%s" % ( l, row [ 0 ], row [ 1 ] ) )
    l += 1

process_rows ( "/path/to/file.tsv" )
process_rows ( [ ["John", "Smith"], ["Karl", "Marx"], ["Emmanuel", "Kant"] ] )
process_rows ( sys.stdin )
```

Now, my questions is: am I reinventing the wheel? Is there any utility around that does the same and that I don't have to rewrite?

### Edit

I've rewritten the function above in a simpler way, thanks to the [suggestion by Masklin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64822688/529286). Old version was:

```py
def process_doc_rows ( rows_source ):
    if ( type ( rows_source ) is str ):
        # Open the file with the csv reader
        with open ( rows_source ) as csvf:
            for row in process_doc_rows ( csvf ):
                yield row
            return
    
    elif isinstance ( rows_source, io.TextIOWrapper ):
        # This includes stdin
        rows_source = csv.reader ( rows_source, delimiter = "\t" )
    
    elif isinstance ( rows_source, Iterable ) or isinstance ( rows_source, Iterator ):
        rows_source = (e for e in rows_source)
    
    elif isinstance ( rows_source, types.GeneratorType ):
        raise TypeError ( "This function wants a file or a CSV-like generator" )
    
    # We must do this in order to avoid the mix of return and yield
    for row in rows_source:
        yield row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any utility around that does the same and that I don't have to rewrite?

Not really, APIs generally try to be more defined than "a file name or a file object or an iterator", though I expect those which work that way also handroll it.

Your system is overly complicated though (and wrong): iterables, iterators and generators are all iterable, you can just leave them to the final loop (which is also unnecessary as `yield from` takes care of this).

And there's a complexity you're not dealing with, which is what not all file-like objects are TextIOWrappers e.g. `StringIO`. I'd suggest either checking for [`TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase) instead, or looking for a `read` method (though that's not what `csv.reader` actually looks for, and furthermore would allow raw IO objects).

```py
def get_rows(rows_source):
    """ Obtains a rows iterator from the input:

    * a string is assumed to be a file path, and read as a TSV file
    * a file-like object is parsed as TSV
    * other iterables are returned as-is
    """
    if isinstance(rows_source, str):
        with open(rows_source, encoding="utf-8") as csvf:
            yield from process_doc_rows(csvf)
        return
    elif isinstance(rows_source, io.TextIOBase):
        rows_source = csv.reader(rows_source, delimiter="\t")
    
    yield from rows_source
```

Comment: ah, you're right, initially, I wasn't using yield at the end, that's why I wrote those ifs. I didn't know about `yield from`, thanks! I've rewritten it the way you proposed.

Answer (score -1):

If your function has to examine the type of its argument before proceeding, it's doing too much work. Your function should focus on iterating over and working with each element of an iterable.

```
def process_rows(rows):
    for row in rows:
        process_row(row))


with open("foo.csv") as f:
    process_rows(csv.reader(f))
```

An additional function can handle splitting each row into fields:

```
def process_csv_rows(rows):
    process_rows(csv.reader(rows))


with open("foo.csv") as f:
    process_csv_rows(f)
```

or even open the file for you:

```
def process_csv_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        process_csv_rows(f)


process_csv_file("foo.csv")
```

Comment: "If your function has to examine the type of its argument before proceeding, it's doing too much work" => that's why I want an helper to turn the input into something I can just iterate over, for the benefit of many functions in need to do so.

process_csv_rows isn't good enough, cause I'd need to write the same for those many functions (plus, Python doesn't allow for method/function overloading, but that's another story).

Comment: It's a matter of being explicit about what you are doing. You, as the programmer, know when you are passing a file name rather than an iterable of rows to the function, so just pass it as an argument to the *right* function.  (And if you *don't* know if the value of a particular variable is going to be a file name or an iterable or rows, you likely have bigger design issues to worry about.)

Comment: No, the many functions I'm writing for a library will receive values in different forms: file paths, stdin (ie, file handlers), test lists. They won't know in advance what the programmer will need to send in and having to write xxx + xxx_csv + xxx_file for every xxx is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm saying, *make* it the programmer's job to specify that. It's much easier and cleaner for *them* to use the right function that for you to try to guess.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you're not getting the point. I am writing that lib and I don't know what I'll get. So, either I write those xxx_csv and xxx_file functions tens of times (with the same conversion code repeated tens of times), or I let the invoker to deal with the same problem (ie, he/she will have to write those same conversions tens of times). `process_doc_rows()` is my way to factorise that in one place only and let xxx to deal with rows generators only.

Comment: Note, that, even if I wanted to declare those _yyy methods, to make things explicit as you say (not a bad idea in itself), certainly I don't want to write the same conversions over and over again. Indeed, I'm trying to factorise some code where that was written already 3-4 times (which, to me is already too many).